# Method Resolution Order (MRO) with mypy type check?

Tags: python, mypy

While working through a custom django mixin, I came across code with the following structure:

```py
class A:
    def method(self, i): # this is a method provided by django, so can't easily change this signature
        print(f"A: {i}")


class B:
    def method(self, i: int): # with type hint
        print(f"B: {i}")
        super().method(i)


class C(B, A):
    pass

# at some point
C().method(0)
```

mypy gives `error: "method" undefined in superclass`.  For now, the workaround I use is to treat `method` as dynamically typed (i.e drop the `int`).  Is it possible to (or does it make sense to) add type annotations so `method` is treated as statically typed?  Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't sound like it has anything to do with the lack of type hints on `A.method`. Also, nothing in this code makes any reference to anything called `m`, so that error message makes no sense. The *actual* error message mypy produces for this code is `main.py:9: error: "method" undefined in superclass`, because `B` does not inherit from anything with a method named `method`.

Comment: mypy is just terrible with mixins for now. There's no good solution, only workarounds.

Comment: Tahnks @user2357112supportsMonica you are right, "m" is a typo, it's "method" instead. fixed.